# Program in C which prints characters of string using pointers

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, pointers, c-strings

hey I am a beginner in C and I am trying to understand pointers so i created two loops

In the first loop I am print every character of my string

In the second loop I try to copy the content from *w to *s

After that i move the pointers

but when I ran the code the terminal and it shows only the number 2

What is going wrong??

**My terminal shows :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/21j3x.jpg

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char sent1[]="my dog barks";
    
    char sent2[]="I love my children";
    int i=0;
    char *s;
    char *w;
    
    s=sent1;
    w=sent2;
    
for(s=sent1;*s;s++)
{
    printf("\n the words are %c" ,*s); 
    
    }   
    
    printf("\n");
    

while (*w) {
    *s = *w;
    s++;
    w++;
    printf("\n the words are %c" ,*s);
}
*s = *w;













    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are breaking array bounds by copying the longer string to the shorter one, and anyway `s` no longer points anywhere valid, due to the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the array `sent1` has only elements to store the default value `"my dog barks"`. Writing (or reading) beyond the last element is prohibited and doing so will invoke *undefined behavior*. You should specify the number of elements explicitly to allocate enough elements.

Secondly, you are printing the value of `*s` after doing increment `s++;`. After the increment, `s` is pointing at a new place where the data from `w` is not written yet. Printing should come before the increment.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char sent1[64]="my dog barks"; /* allocate enough elements */
    
    char sent2[]="I love my children";
    int i=0;
    char *s;
    char *w;
    
    s=sent1;
    w=sent2;
    
    for(s=sent1;*s;s++)
    {
        printf("\n the words are %c" ,*s);
    
    }   
    
    printf("\n");
    

    while (*w) {
        *s = *w;
        printf("\n the words are %c" ,*s); /* print data before incrementing */
        s++;
        w++;
    }
    *s = *w;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters these headers

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
```

are redundant in your program because neither declaration from the headers is used in your program.

Now let's consider the first for loop.

Before the loop you assigned the pointer `s` with the address of the first character of the array `sent1`

```
s=sent1;
```

Then in the for loop you reassigned the pointer `s` with the same value

```
for(s=sent1;*s;s++)
```

So the previous assignment was redundant.

Try use variables in the minimal scope where they are used.

Instead of this code snippet

```
char *s;
char *w;

s=sent1;
w=sent2;

for(s=sent1;*s;s++)
{
    printf("\n the words are %c" ,*s); 
}
```

You could write

```
printf("\n the words are ";
for( const char *s = sent1; *s; s++ )
{
    printf( "%c", *s ); 
}
```

After your first for loop

```
for(s=sent1;*s;s++)
{
    printf("\n the words are %c" ,*s); 

}
```

the pointer `s` points tp the zero terminating character. So using the pointer in the next while loop

```
while (*w) {
    *s = *w;
    s++;
    w++;
    printf("\n the words are %c" ,*s);
}
```

results in undefined behavior. You need at least reset the pointer `s` to the address of the first character of the array `sent1`

```
s = sent1;
while (*w) {
    *s = *w;
    s++;
    w++;
    printf("\n the words are %c" ,*s);
}
```

Also before the call of `printf`

```
printf("\n the words are %c" ,*s);
```

you already incremented the pointer `s`

```
s++;
```

So the output of the first character will be skipped.

Moreover the size of the array `sent1` is less than the size of the array `sent2`. Thus copying the string stored in the array `sent2` in the array `sent1` again results in undefined behavior.

If to follow the description of what you are trying to do

> In the first loop I am print every character of my string
>
> In the second loop I try to copy the content from *w to *s

then the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char sent1[] = "I love my children";
    char sent2[ sizeof( sent1 ) ] = "my dog barks";
    
    printf( "\n the words are " );
    
    for ( const char *s = sent2; *s; ++s )
    {
        putchar( *s );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    const char *w = sent1;
    char *s = sent2;
    
    do
    {
        *s++ = *w;
    } while ( *w++ );
    

    printf( "\n the words are " );
    
    for ( const char *s = sent2; *s; ++s )
    {
        putchar( *s );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 the words are my dog barks

 the words are I love my children
```